# Repeat AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have a doubt about the possibility of repeating an AsyncTask in an application for Android. I would like to repeat some operations, the download of a file from a server for example, n times if it is impossible for some reasons download the file. There is a quick way to do this?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? You can just start up the same AsyncTask again if it failed.

Comment: use service and alaram manager class for repeating Async Task

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You cannot repeat an AsyncTask **but** you could repeat the operations it executes.

I've made this little helper class that you might want to extend in place of AsyncTask, the only big difference is that you will use repeatInBackground instead of doInBackground and that onPostExecute will have a new parameter, the eventual Exception thrown.

Anything inside repeatInBackground will be repeated automatically until result is different from null / exception is not thrown and there are been less than maxTries.

The last exception thrown inside the loop will be returned in the onPostExecute(Result, Exception).

You can set max tries using the RepeatableAsyncTask(int retries) constructor.

```
public abstract class RepeatableAsyncTask<A, B, C> extends AsyncTask<A, B, C> {
    private static final String TAG = "RepeatableAsyncTask";
    public static final int DEFAULT_MAX_RETRY = 5;

    private int mMaxRetries = DEFAULT_MAX_RETRY;
    private Exception mException = null;

    /**
     * Default constructor
     */
    public RepeatableAsyncTask() {
        super();
    }

    /**
     * Constructs an AsyncTask that will repeate itself for max Retries
     * @param retries Max Retries.
     */
    public RepeatableAsyncTask(int retries) {
        super();
        mMaxRetries = retries;
    }

    /**
     * Will be repeated for max retries while the result is null or an exception is thrown.
     * @param inputs Same as AsyncTask's
     * @return Same as AsyncTask's
     */
    protected abstract C repeatInBackground(A...inputs);

    @Override
    protected final C doInBackground(A...inputs) {
        int tries = 0;
        C result = null;

        /* This is the main loop, repeatInBackground will be repeated until result will not be null */
        while(tries++ < mMaxRetries && result == null) {
            try {
                result = repeatInBackground(inputs);
            } catch (Exception exception) {
                /* You might want to log the exception everytime, do it here. */
                mException = exception;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    /**
     * Like onPostExecute but will return an eventual Exception
     * @param c Result same as AsyncTask
     * @param exception Exception thrown in the loop, even if the result is not null.
     */
    protected abstract void onPostExecute(C c, Exception exception);

    @Override
    protected final void onPostExecute(C c) {
        super.onPostExecute(c);
        onPostExecute(c, mException);
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this work as a static class?  I like to use static AsyncTasks to avoid the dangling reference during an orientation change.  Do you know if your class works statically?

Comment: I always use it statically.

Comment: Could something like a delay be added between tries? For example to make queries every second.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot reuse the same `AsyncTask` object as, [according to the AsyncTask Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

> The task can be executed only once (an exception will be thrown if a second execution is attempted.)

But you can create however many new objects of that class you need inside of a loop. However a better way you be to do the download operation n number of times inside your `doInBackground()`.

If this doesn't answer your question then please be more specific as to your problem

Answer (score 0):

I did it that way. It can try and try until (tries == MAX_RETRY) or the result is not null. A slightly modified code from accepted answer, better for me.

```
private class RssReaderTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<RssItem>> {

    // max number of tries when something is wrong
    private static final int MAX_RETRY = 3;

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<RssItem> doInBackground(String... params) {

        ArrayList<RssItem> result = null;
        int tries = 0;

        while(tries++ < MAX_RETRY && result == null) {
            try {
                Log.i("RssReaderTask", "********** doInBackground: Processing... Trial: " + tries);
                URL url = new URL(params[0]);
                RssFeed feed = RssReader.read(url);
                result = feed.getRssItems();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Log.i("RssReaderTask", "********** doInBackground: Feed error!");
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<RssItem> result) {
        // deal with result
    }

}
```