# ArrayOutOfBound error when on mobile internet, but works on WiFi

Tags: android, google-maps, android-asynctask, indexoutofboundsexception

I am making an RSS reader application where I am getting coordinates from an xml file and I am then ploting them on maps. I call this async task but gives me:

*java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException* on a slow internet connection. Also just for info I am running another async in a different fragment side by side!

Here the code for this async:

```
void getDataInAsyncTask(){
    final ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog(getActivity(), ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);

    pd.setTitle("Loading ...");
    pd.setCancelable(false);
    pd.setIndeterminate(true);
    pd.setMessage("Please wait while we load nearby restaurants");
    AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<Data>> task = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<Data>>() {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        pd.show();
    }
    protected List<Data> doInBackground(Void... urls) {
        // Debug the task thread name
        Log.d("ITCRssReader", "inside");
        try {
            // Create RSS reader
            RssReader rssReader = new RssReader("http://findaway.in/card/restaurants/feed.xml");
            Log.d("ITCRssReader", "inside1");
            // Parse RSS, get items
            // Log.d("ITCRssReader", rssReader.getItems().get(3).getName());
            return rssReader.getItems();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Slow or No Internet Connection",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(List<Data> result) {
        Log.d("Map", result.get(3).getName());// <-chal raha hai yaha tk
        MapList = new ArrayList<Data>(result);
        // Get a ListView from main view
        int i=0;
        for(i=0 ; i<MapList.size();i++)
            {
                Log.d("map latlong",MapList.get(i).getLatLong());
                String loc = MapList.get(i).getLatLong();
                String s[] = loc.split(",");
                LatLng mylocation=new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(s[0]),Double.parseDouble(s[1]));
                //Log.d("Location","Double.parseDouble(s[0]),Double.parseDouble(s[1])");
                Marker m = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(mylocation)
                           .title(MapList.get(i).getName()));
                //m.showInfoWindow();
            }
            pd.dismiss();   
        }
    };
    task.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
}
```

Here my log cat:

[image]

Comment: `String s[] = loc.split(",");` didn't split anything, i.e. there is no comma in the `loc` string - you need to find out why.

Comment: Not complete `result` was received so `loc` had only `28`.

Comment: I am recieving 85 objects in result array i just checked which are comming all correct , the log prints all the 85 coordinates when internet speed is high but fails when it is low there's something happening wrong in between due to slow fetching of data i suppose what can i do ? how to handle this thing ? refresh the fragment / try catch ?

Comment: Maybe [Repeat AsyncTask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18359039/repeat-asynctask) could help.